# Next.js saving id passed from next/Link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am having some issues with the way I currently have the flow set up. I have a component `ArticeList` that is listening to articles and when clicking on it it will redirect you to the individual article page. I am using `next/Link` to redirect the article to its landing page and passing the id as a hidden query using the Link attribute `as` for example:

```
<Link href={`/article/${ConvertTitleToURL(data.name)}/?id=${data.id}`} as={`/article/${ConvertTitleToURL(data.name)}`}>
```

I am then using `next/router` on my `[...article].js` page to get the hidden id and use it fetch the article content. For example:

```
     const router = useRouter()
        const articleId = router.query.id
    
    const apiURL = 'https://test.api/' + id

const { data, error } = useSWR(`${apiURL}`, fetcher)
```

I am able to successfully make this call with the way it's currently set up but my issue is if the user refreshes the page the id that was originally passed from `Link` is now loss and I get an error because `articleId` equals nothing.

Is it possible to save the article id on the first load so if a user refreshes the page the content will still load?

I've attempted to solve this issue by using a react hook but I am still receiving the same error. How can I work around this?

Here is my code sample:

ArticleList component which links passing the id

```
import Link from 'next/link'

    function ConvertCodeTitleToURL(title) {
        let url = ""
    
        if (title) {
            url = title.replace(".","").toLowerCase()
            url = url.replace(/,/g, "")
            url = url.replace("(", "")     // added for (except) cases
            url = url.replace(/\s/g, "-")
        } else {
            url = "/"
        }
        
        return url
    }
    
    
    const ArticleList = ({articles}) => {
        
        return (
        <div className="container-1200">
                {articles && articles.map(data => (
                    <div key={data.id}> 
                {data.results.length > 0 && 
            <div key={data.id}> 
                <div  className="d-flex justify-space-between">
                <div className="heading-30 letter-spacing-25 text-dark-blue m-l-n-20">{data.name}</div>
                <Link href={`/articles/${ConvertCodeTitleToURL(data.name)}/?id=${data.id}`} as={`/articles/${ConvertCodeTitleToURL(data.name)}`}> 
                </Link>
                 </div>
            </div>
                            }
                            </div>
                ))}
        </div>
    )
        }
    export default ArticleList
```

article page which is using the id passed from `Link` to fetch data

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import useSWR from 'swr'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import ArticleLayout from '../../components/ArticleLayout';

const fetcher = (...args) => fetch(...args).then(res => res.json())


function Articles() {

    const router = useRouter()
    const articleId = router.query.id

    const [id, setId] = useState(articleId);


    const apiURL = 'https://test.api/' + id

    const { data, error } = useSWR(`${apiURL}`, fetcher)
 
    if (error) return <div>failed to load ...</div>
    if (!data) return <div>loading....</div>

    return (
        <>
        <ArticleLayout article={data}/>
        </>
    )
}


export default Articles
```

Comment: Is there a reason to hide the id? If you have to hide the id, you could store it in localStorage so it can be recovered after a refresh.

Comment: For this project, the URLs need to be clean without the ids. I'll have a look into storing it in localStorage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save / load id from localStorage. Note that it doesn't handle edge cases.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import useSWR from 'swr'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import ArticleLayout from '../../components/ArticleLayout';

const ISSERVER = typeof window === "undefined";

const fetcher = (...args) => fetch(...args).then(res => res.json())


function Articles() {

    const router = useRouter()
    const [id, setId] = useState(() => {
      const articleId = router.query.id
      if (ISSERVER) return articleId;
      if (articleId) {
         localStorage.set("articleId", articleId);
         return articleId;
      } else {
         return localStorage.get("articleId");
      }
    });


    const apiURL = 'https://test.api/' + id

    const { data, error } = useSWR(`${apiURL}`, fetcher)
 
    if (error) return <div>failed to load ...</div>
    if (!data) return <div>loading....</div>

    return (
        <>
        <ArticleLayout article={data}/>
        </>
    )
}


export default Articles
```

Answer (score 0):

useRouter take time to load when you reload page. you can do conditinal fetching on useSWR hook

```
const router = useRouter()
const articleId = router?.query?.id || '' //check if id exist 
const apiURL = 'https://test.api/' + id

//conditional fetching, null means fetch nothing if articleId not true
const { data, error } = useSWR(articleId ?`${apiURL}`:null, fetcher)
```

Comment: This works to get rid of the error but the data doesn't return. I don't think the id is retained on refresh